# Add elements to collection conditionally

Tags: javascript

Is there a smarter way to write this code?  I used to add all the elements in the collection constructor, something like this:

```
new OrderWizardStateCollection([new OrderWizardState(..), new OrderWizardState(..)..])
```

but now, since I have this one conditional addition, I'm writing it this way:

```
this.state_collection = new OrderWizardStateCollection();
this.state_collection.add(new OrderWizardState({ state: 'basket', phase: this.phase_collection.findWhere({ phase: 'basket' }) }));
this.state_collection.add(new OrderWizardState({ state: 'account', phase: this.phase_collection.findWhere({ phase: 'account' }) }));
if ( _.has(this.regions, "lp") ) this.state_collection.add(new OrderWizardState({ state: 'loyaltypoints', phase: this.phase_collection.findWhere({ phase: 'account' }) }));
this.state_collection.add(new OrderWizardState({ state: 'delivery', phase: this.phase_collection.findWhere({ phase: 'delivery' }) }));
this.state_collection.add(new OrderWizardState({ state: 'payment', phase: this.phase_collection.findWhere({ phase: 'payment' }) }));
this.state_collection.add(new OrderWizardState({ state: 'placeorder', phase: this.phase_collection.findWhere({ phase: 'placeorder' }) }));
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do a loop over the elements that you are always adding:

```
for (var info in ["basket", "account", "delivery", "payment", "placeorder"] {
    this.state_collection.add (new OrderWizardState ({ state: info, phase: this.phase_collection.findWhere ({ phase: info }) }));
}
```

And to add the special one, you use your `if` statement and `insert` it at a specific index:

```
if ( _.has (this.regions, "lp")) { 
    var state = new OrderWizardState({ state: 'loyaltypoints', phase: this.phase_collection.findWhere({ phase: 'account' }) })
    this.state_collection.insert (2, state);
}
```

Comment: Don't use `for..in` on arrays in javascript; it enumerates properties - not just the array's elements (also, that line is missing a `)`). Use a regular `for`, or maybe call `forEach`, or use `_.each` since underscore/lodash seems to be there.